# Angular: Override injected dependencies of a service

Tags: angular

I am trying to test a component:

```
    @Component({...})
    class MyComponent {
      private serviceA = inject(ServiceA);
    }
```

Service A has a dependency:

```
    @Injectable({...})
    class ServiceA {
      protected serviceB = inject(ServiceB);
    }
```

ServiceB has also dependencies:

```
    @Injectable({...})
    class ServiceB {
      private serviceC = inject(ServiceC);
    }
```

So What I am trying to do to bypass the dependency injections, is to Mock service A with a partial object:

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class MockServiceA extends ServiceA {
      override serviceB = {...} as ServiceB;
    }
```

And Inject it to the TestBed:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [MyComponent],
          providers: [
            { provide: ServiceA, useClass: MockServiceA },
          ]
        });
```

But the dependency injection problem is still there: compiler ask me to provide a value for ServiceB to provide it to Service A.

Has anybody an idea how to fix it or a better approach ?
Also MyComponent does not content child components so the dependency issue cannot come from there.

Comment: No need to extend `ServiceA` in the mock. Removing `extends ServiceA` will also get rid of the dependency to `ServiceB`.

Comment: Yes but not extending the ServiceA will make me paste every method from ServiceA into MockServiceA ..

Comment: But you probably don't want to use the actual code of ServiceA in the test. So the mock needs to take care of all the methods. You don't have to code that, but instead use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). See [jest-mock-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-proxy) for example.